# How to create pojo class of Object of ArrayList from REST API response?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit2

I'm working on project in which I have to implement on API. This API repsonse is objects of ArrayList. Can you please help me with creating its POJO class and if possible its implementation. I'm using retrofit2 & GSON.

As shown in following JSON schema, brand names will be added in `brandsonly` by admin, and it will be added in `allorders` as a arraylist which have multiple sub-objects.

Like, if admin add `Redmi` in the `brandsonly` then it will create `Redmi[]` in the `allorders`

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "brandsonly": [
        {
            "_id": "",
            "brandname": "SAMSUNG",
        },
        {
            "_id": "",
            "brandname": "VIVO",
        },
        {
            "_id": "",
            "brandname": "NOKIA"
        },
        {
            "_id": "",
            "brandname": "IPHONE",
        }
    ],
    "allorders": {
        "SAMSUNG": [],
        "VIVO": [],
        "NOKIA": [],
        "IPHONE": [
            {
                "_id": "",
                "order_id": "",
                "__v": 0,
                "adminconfirmation": 1,
                "finalpricetodeduct": 30950
            },
            {
                "_id": "",
                "order_id": "",
                "__v": 0,
                "adminconfirmation": 1,
                "finalpricetodeduct": 
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

My Retrofit call from activity:

```
        final AllOrdersResponse allOrdersResponse = new AllOrdersResponse(userID);
        Call<AllOrdersResponse> responseCall = retrofit_interface.allOrderResponse(allOrdersResponse, "Bearer " + AuthToken);

        responseCall.enqueue(new Callback<AllOrdersResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<AllOrdersResponse> call, @NotNull Response<AllOrdersResponse> response) {
                AllOrdersResponse response1 = response.body();
            
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<AllOrdersResponse> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
                if (t instanceof SocketTimeoutException)
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Socket Time out. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(context, t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Offtopic: Have a look at OpenAPI Standard. There are a couple of API generator for client and server for multiple languages.

Comment: You can use online json to POJO converter sites

Comment: @Rajesh I know, but this time I need help in logic.

Comment: @FaltFe Thank you for your suggestions. But I'm only working on Android part, my backend team is providing me this apis.

Comment: Use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ for generating pojo classes

Answer (score 0):

I dont think a POJO schema would work in this instance as it will always change. It would be much better is the `allorders` was the same as `brandsonly` a JSON Array of JSON Array

However, if that cannot be changed have a look at the below.

```
    final AllOrdersResponse allOrdersResponse = new AllOrdersResponse(userID);
    Call<AllOrdersResponse> responseCall = retrofit_interface.allOrderResponse(allOrdersResponse, "Bearer " + AuthToken);

    responseCall.enqueue(new Callback<AllOrdersResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<AllOrdersResponse> call, @NotNull Response<AllOrdersResponse> response) {
            AllOrdersResponse response1 = response.body();
            List<String> brands = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Map<String, Product>> products = new ArrayList<>();
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response1); 
            for(JSONObject brand : jsonObject.get("brandsonly")){
                 brands.add(brand.getvalue("brandname"));
            }

             if(brands.size= > 0){
                for(String brandname: brands){
                    HashMap<String, Product> tempHash = new HashMap<>();
                    JSONArray temp = jsonObject.getJSONArray(brandname);
                    foreach(JSONObject x : temp){
                           Product product = new Product();
                           product.FromJSONObject(x);
                           temp.put(brandname, product);
                    }
                    products.add(tempHash);
              }
           }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<AllOrdersResponse> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
            if (t instanceof SocketTimeoutException)
                Toast.makeText(context, "Socket Time out. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(context, t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

So you have a list of BandNames with a value of each product.

I would also recommend looking at [jsonschema2.pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Comment: Thank you @TDIScott for solution. What will be there inside Product class?? I created response POJO but didn't find FromJSONObject method.

Comment: What is response here ```JSONObject(response)```??

Comment: Sorry the  `response` is the API response (objects of ArrayList)

Comment: I've updated my question, can you please tell me from where I will get that response?? Because ```JSONObject``` requires String response and my call giving ```AllOrdersResponse``` object.

Comment: I changed the answer to better reflect the Retrofit class you have provided

Comment: Can you clear few questions? Product is a POJO class of response inside IPHONE array (i.e. sub arraylists)?? JSONObject showing error on response (Cannot resolve constructor, it is only accepting string values). 
foreach not applicable to type 'java.lang.Object'.
FromJSONObject is a method from product class and what it will contain??